# How to get rid of ugly SWT button fringes in Windows 7?

Tags: java, windows-7, swt, jface

I maintain a **SWT/JFace** application that has to run in **Windows XP** as well as **Windows 7**.
The application has a `TabFolder` that contains a `Composite`, that in turn contains the widgets. Nothing unusual and everything works well except for...

---

### The Buttons

While they look OK in Windows XP they have an ugly grey border in Windows 7.

[image]
[image]

---

[image]

I could set the background of the button manually but I failed to figure out a
way to find out the parents actual background color. `getBackground()` returns always 240, 240, 240 even if the background is actually white.

I found out that in Windows XP the background of a TabFolder is the theme color **3D Objects** while in Windows 7 there is not such correspondence. I tried to set every single
theme color to bright red but the TabFolder background color was unimpressed.

So the SWT buttons don't set their background color correctly themselves and I see no way to find out the correct color programatically. What should I do?

---

Anyway, here is the code for a complete minimal example to reproduce the problem:

```java
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabFolder;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabItem;

public class TabTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);

        TabFolder tabFolder = new TabFolder (shell, SWT.NONE);
        TabItem item = new TabItem (tabFolder, SWT.NULL);
        item.setText ("Tab Item");

        Composite comp = new Composite(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
        comp.setLayout(new RowLayout());
        item.setControl(comp);

        Button button = new Button(comp, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText("Button ");
        tabFolder.setSize (160, 100);

        //Event Loop
        shell.pack ();
        shell.open ();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
         if (!display.readAndDispatch())
          display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems more like a platform issue than a SWT problem. Although not related but there was a platform [specific bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=25615) for `setBackground()` of `TabFolder`, it may or may not be related to your current problem.

One ***workaround*** is to use `CTabFolder`. See the below snippet and output:

**`Output on Windows 7, using JDK 1.6_b30, Eclipse 3.7`**

[image]

**`Code:`**

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabFolder;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabItem;

public class TabTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        shell.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        CTabFolder tabFolder = new CTabFolder (shell, SWT.BORDER|SWT.FLAT);
        tabFolder.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        tabFolder.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        CTabItem item = new CTabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NULL);
        item.setText ("Tab Item");

        Composite comp = new Composite(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
        comp.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        comp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        item.setControl(comp);

        Button button = new Button(comp, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText("Button ");
        tabFolder.setSize (160, 100);

        item = new CTabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NULL);
        item.setText ("Tab Item");

        //Event Loop
        shell.pack ();
        shell.open ();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
         if (!display.readAndDispatch())
          display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your composite that holds the button set the background mode to SWT.INHERIT_FORCE

```
    comp.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);
```

Comment: Have you tried it? I added `comp.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);` as line 23 and it changed nothing.